# Unzipped fastPHASE does not work on MAC system (instead of a file, a blank document produced)

Tags: statistics, bioinformatics, imputation

Trying to do imputation performence assessment with fastPHASE. According to the document, there should be a file which has the samiliar name as "macOSfp.tar", but instead I got an empty file on my MAC desktop.

The command I typed in the terminal:

```
% gunzip macOSfp.tar.gz
tar -xvf macOSfp.tar
```

[The unzipped file and the empty file I got after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtoCw.png)

The document link http://scheet.org/code/fastphase_doc_1.4.pdf

I wonder if anyone has encountered the same problem before or knows why this happened.

Thank you so much.

For convenience, this is part of the installation in the documentation.

**2.1 Installation**

Presumably, you have downloaded a fastphase.VERSION.linux.tar.gz file.(Alternatively, you downloaded an executable file for Solaris, Darwin1, or for Microsoft Windows2.)Then do the following:

```
gunzip fastphase.VERSION.linux.tar.gz

tar -xvf fastphase.VERSION.linux.tar
```

This will produce a folder similar in name to fastphase.VERSION.linux.
Contained in this new directory are the following:

• fastPHASE

• fastphase.inp an example input file

• fastphase haplotypes.inp an example input file of known haplotypes

• fastphase subpoplabels.inp file of “subpopulation” labels for individuals in fastphase.inp

• fastphase subpoplabels2.inp contains enough labels to run with
-b -ufastphase  subpoplabels2.inp flags.

Comment: This is probably more relavent on the bioinformatics stack exchange site

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Erik.

Comment: sloved with this command, hope this will help someone who has the same problem in the furture. chmod +x fastPHASE

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it after one day